# Invalid syntax when trying to add patch_http_response_read patch

Tags: python-3.x

Hello i'm trying to patch my python code with http://bobrochel.blogspot.com/2010/11/bad-servers-chunked-encoding-and.html but when adding this snippet anywhere in the code I always get invalid syntax. What am I doing wrong?

The start of my code looks like this:

```
import logging
import argparse
import sys
from arbitrer import Arbitrer


def patch_http_response_read(func):
     def inner(*args):
    try:
        return func(*args)
    except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:
        return e.partial

return inner
httplib.HTTPResponse.read = patch_http_response_read(httplib.HTTPResponse.read)


class ArbitrerCLI:
def __init__(self):
```

Comment: Indent correctly. Indentation is a part of python syntax.

Comment: It's not indent it's invalid syntax here:   except httplib.IncompleteRead, e: somewhere near ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`except` doesn't work that way anymore.

```
except httplib.IncompleteRead as e:
```

Answer (score 1):

Indent correctly.

[The try statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) changed in Python 3.x.

```
import httplib
import logging
import argparse
import sys
from arbitrer import Arbitrer


def patch_http_response_read(func):
    def inner(*args):
        try:
            return func(*args)
        except httplib.IncompleteRead as e:
            return e.partial
    return inner

httplib.HTTPResponse.read = patch_http_response_read(httplib.HTTPResponse.read)


class ArbitrerCLI:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```